xArray + geopandas + iterate through each polygon and get basic statistics
I come to the community to ask help for some issues regarding xarrary + geopandas for time series data analysis.
I have a xarray dataset called cum_magn_ds that looks like this:
xarray.Dataset
Dimensions:
time: 16y: 3001x: 3000
Coordinates:
x (x) float64 3.942e+05 3.942e+05 ... 4.392e+05
y (y) float64 6.673e+06 6.673e+06 ... 6.628e+06
time (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-03-31 ... 2024-01-13
Data variables:
cum_disp (time, y, x) float64 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
Attributes:
AREA_OR_POINT : Area
STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE : YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM : 61.55648635672
STATISTICS_MEAN : 2.2860794614348
STATISTICS_MINIMUM : 0.0048748816705561
STATISTICS_STDDEV : 2.9354504034697
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT : 76.11

On the other hand, I have a geopackages file containing 200 polygons. The GeoDataframe called selected_gdf looks like this:
    area_m2 id  geometry
53  100636.350443   385 MULTIPOLYGON (((412065.000 6663985.000, 412065...
56  79473.343769    401 MULTIPOLYGON (((411855.000 6663685.000, 411855...
167 754674.777833   1280    MULTIPOLYGON (((415935.000 6645895.000, 415935...

What I want to do is:
- iterate though each polygon, go to slice clip the xArray_dataset and compute basic statistics, mean for instance. When I make this processing with a single polygon, it works and I got good results (see the code below):
#  Getting the biggest polygon
single_poly_gdf = gdf.loc[[gdf['area_m2'].idxmax()]]
# Clipping with rio.cpli within xArary
cum_magn_ds.rio.clip(single_poly_gdf.geometry.values, single_poly_gdf.crs).cum_disp.mean(dim=["x", "y"], skipna=True)

The result:
xarray.DataArray'cum_disp'time: 16
array([ 1.58297256,  1.73710292,  3.53712282,  4.27412698, 19.88154365,
       20.90266202, 21.16476275, 21.99914255, 24.88651852, 25.80484704,
       26.92583463, 28.62922104, 29.28387035, 31.90287332, 32.59387569,
       31.56232418])
Coordinates:
time (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-03-31 ... 2024-01-13
spatial_ref () int64 0
Attributes: (0)

The dtype of single_poly_gdf is geopandas.array.GeometryArray.
The problem arises when I want to work with the large GeoDataFrame (200 polygons).
I have problems getting the geometry for each polygon (row) and passing through the xArray_dataset.rio.clip(...).
I tried the following code, but I have problems with the geometry:
results_from_three = []

for row in selected_gdf.iterfeatures():
    # print(type(row))
    # print(row['geometry']['coordinates'])
    aoi_coords = row['geometry']['coordinates']
    # print(aoi_coords)
    aoi = cum_magn_ds.rio.clip(aoi_coords)
    mp = aoi.cum_disp.mean(dim=["x", "y"], skipna=True)
    results_from_three.append(mp)

# Concatenate results into a single DataFrame
df = xr.concat(results_from_three, dim='polygon').to_dataframe()

Do you have some suggestions to solve the problem? notably on getting the geometry for each row? Or even if you have some suggestion to improve the code, I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance

clip expects a geometry not coordinates, so you might want to try something like that with iterrows :
results_from_three = []

for index, row in selected_gdf.iterrows():
    aoi = cum_magn_ds.rio.clip([row['geometry']])
    mp = aoi.cum_disp.mean(dim=["x", "y"], skipna=True)
    results_from_three.append(mp)


Thanks a lot... it worked using the geometry an iterrows
